# How can I define value´s format of a cell based in a variable?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc, devexpress-wpf

I would like to set the format of a cell based on another value:
In my example if value1 = "percent", value2 will appear like 10%.
If value1 = "two", value2 will appear line 10.00, and so on...

```
<dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[value1] = 'percent'" FieldName="value2">
    <dxg:Format />
</dxg:FormatCondition>
```

Is there any kind of mask in  or setting the value of the cell (using Eval or similar) for achieving this?

Thanks guys...

EDITED:
Maybe could be set here...

```
<TextBlock Name="value2_name" Text="{Binding Data.value2}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.

The idea could be handle all from server-side.

Like:

-- XAML --

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Limit" AllowEditing="True" Width="80">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Background="#FFFF99">
                                <dxe:SpinEdit Name="PART_Editor" IsEnabled="{Binding Data.IsEnabledLimit}" Mask="{Binding Data.MaskLimit}" MaskType="Numeric" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

-- CONTROLLER --

```
    public string MaskLimit
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Designation == Constant.HEADER_RF)
            {
                return "###.##%";
            }
            else
            {
                return "###.######";
            }
        }
    }
```

Hoping it helps...